# How to apply a key/value to a link using a separate key/value in the same object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on the value **key1:V3**

- I need to store the value **keyA:VB** into a var then into the link1 anchor.
- I need to store the value **keyA:VD** into a var then into the link2 anchor.

I have been working on this for a while and i cant figure it out.  Please help.

```js
var foo = [
    {"key1": "V1", "keyA": "VA"},
    {"key1": "V2", "keyA": "VB"},
    {"key1": "V3", "keyA": "VC"},
    {"key1": "V4", "keyA": "VD"},
    {"key1": "V5", "keyA": "VE"}
  ];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link1" href="#"></a>
<a id="link2" href="#"></a>
```

I need the outcome html code to be:

```html
<a id="link1" href="#">VB</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">VD</a>
```

Thank you in advance

**ALTERNATIVE EXAMPLE**

```js
var toc = [
    {"pageNum": "1", "fileName": "index.html"},
    {"pageNum": "2", "fileName": "about.html"},
    {"pageNum": "3", "fileName": "work.html"},
    {"pageNum": "4", "fileName": "blog.html"},
    {"pageNum": "5", "fileName": "contact.html"}
  ];
```

Comment: could you elaborate how  `key1:V3` corresponds with `keyA:VB` and ` keyA:VD`? The pattern I see is selected key, create links with key + 1 and key - 1...

Comment: What is the results you are looking for?

Comment: @Thomas Think of key1 the indexes for a bunch of webpages. KeyA are entries for the corrisponding webpages in the site.  The connection is if V3 is your current page index then V2 is the previous page and V4 is the next page (like in a book) VB is the previous page address and VD is the next page address                                  

**ALTERNATIVE EXAMPLE ABOVE**

Comment: @DustinPoissant The results are in the original post above :::  
---
I need the outcome html code to be:

<a id="link1" href="#">VB</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">VD</a>

Comment: So then what is the rest of the information about? why even have keys if you are not going to use them

Comment: @DustinPoissant Its part of another section of code to dynamically track the total pagination i.e.  Page **1** of **50**

Comment: There is not enough information here for me to begin answering the question. I don't understand what your trying to do or what your output should be. If thats what you want your output to be why not just do that.

Comment: Do you want a link for each object in the array or just the second and fourth as you asked for. And what does key1 have anything to do with the output. I dont see that in the output at all.

Comment: im trying to build a previous page button and a next page button, like changing the page in a book.  if you are on page 2, and you want to keep reading you click a button and it brings you to page 3 or if you want to go back a page you click a button that goes to page 1.  The object array above is like a table of contents, documenting the page numbers, the page URL and their sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myValue = "V3";
for ( var index = 0; index < foo.length; index++ ){
  if ( foo[index].key1 === myValue ){
    document.getElementById( "link1" ).innerHTML = foo[index].keyA;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer to help other users of the site. Code-only answers are not very useful and tend to be marked as low quality and potentially deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After long while i have figured out my issue:

```js
toc.filter(function (toc) {

  prevPageNum = toc.pageNum - 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(toc).length; i++) {
    if (prevPageNum === i) {
      prevPage = toc.fileName;
      $('#prevPage').attr("href",prevPage);
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
});
```

I would truly appreciate if you would remove the "Unclear, Didn't do research" on the main questions. i have been working on this for days.  Thank you.